# Faceting in Wave analytics not happening

Tags: dashboard, einstein-analytics

i have a step type of saql where i have created an derived field, using it in the list filter. Though the broadcast facet and receive facet are set to True in dashboard json. Faceting is not happening. what could be the reason

Answer (score 0):

hey the derived field must have the name or alias same as where it is referred.

if i derive field name as "dimensionN", then in the chart which you are trying to filter based on faceting should contain this field name as "dimensionN"